# JFrame Layout Alignment

Tags: java, swing

I'm having a bit of trouble with JFrame layouts. What I want is this alignment:
[image]
but what I get with this snippet of code is this:

```
    this.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
```

[image]

and with this snippet is this:

```
    this.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

[image]

How can I get the ideal (where each row is centered but the icons start from the left side)?

EDIT: It's a bit hard to see the difference between the first and the last, but just open the images in a new tab and CTRL-TAB between them to see what I mean. In the first image, the entire thing is centered in the screen while in the third the icons are left-aligned. The second has ALL icons centered.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot spot the difference between the first screen shot (the desired result) and the last screen shot :) Oh, now I see. Have you tried to configure some margins / padding etc.?

Comment: I was just about to say that

Comment: Probably should have chosen a background color that's not white. Open the images in a new tab and switch between them - you'll see that in the first the margins between the left and right are equal, whereas in the third it's left-aligned.

Comment: Alright, I changed the background color to black - is it more apparent now? The first one is centered while the third is left-justified.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I ended up just adding the images to a JPanel with the same left-to-right formatting as the third example and centering that JPanel. Simple fix.

Comment: You figured out the most important technique of Swing layout manager wrangling: if the layout manager needs to do two jobs (here forming lines of blocks and centering the lines), liberally add nested JPanels to have extra layout managers at your disposal and make every one of them trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure if that was supposed to be funny, but +1 for making me laugh.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to be funny. People insist on shallow hierarchies of low-level UI widgets instead of building appropriate abstractions, and try to manage overpopulated panels with horribly complex layout managers like GridBagLayout instead of thinking of a proper structure. The API for Swing classes that were actually meant as building blocks is so large and complex that few dare to write their own JComponent subclasses, even if it's actually quite easy.